# Use a Shopify Liquid theme with only Stripe (without Shopify)?

Tags: stripe-payments, shopify, liquid, strip

I have a store that I do no longer maintain nor have available inventory. But I'm interested in keeping the custom made design for demo purpose and portfolio.

It made me wonder if there is an open-source project that generates a static website based on a Shopify export + Shopify theme.

I found this: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-payments-demo
I was wondering if we can have liquid themes integrated?

EDIT: I open source a store that I transformed from stripe to static HTML with shopify: https://github.com/melalj/gabithegoat

Comment: I believe if you use shopify you need to use shopify payments, which is just stripe with shopify making a %...You can choose to use your own payment processor, and I believe you can use Stripe, but they also take percentage.  So if you use stripe itll usually make sense to just use shopify payments

Answer (score 0):

Liquid is open source. You can download Liquid libraries for Ruby, PHP and probably other scripting languages. So it would not be a stretch to re-use your theme code.

Jekyll the static site generator uses Liquid. So you could whip up a demo of your Liquid skills pretty quick using that.

What any of this has to do with Stripe is another matter. No really relevant unless you are saying you want to use Stripe with your Liquid and not Shopify. In which case, huh? Good luck with that effort!